# Spinor helicity formalism - original reference?

Tags: resource-recommendations, scattering, history, spinors, helicity

The [spinor helicity formalism](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1146666.files/IV-3-SpinorHelicity.pdf) is a modern technique widely used in scattering amplitude calculations nowadays. However, it is hard to find a reference for who first came up with the formalism. Maybe someone here knows of the first author to ever use spinor helicity?

EDIT:

Even [this review](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.1697v2.pdf) does not have any reference on the topic. However, they naturally introduce it from a discussion on Dirac and Weyl spinors, so I guess one can attribute the formalism to them.

Comment: Note that the first link -- `http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1146666.files/IV-3-SpinorHelicity.pdf ` --  is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from that there are also bunch of papers which are regarded as earliest developments of spinor helicity formalism, for example

http://inspirehep.net/record/167680?ln=en

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321382904898

http://inspirehep.net/record/231187?ln=en

http://inspirehep.net/record/302550?ln=en

Dixon cite those in his review paper

https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.5353

Comment: Before answering, please see our policy on resource recommendation questions. Please write substantial answers that detail the style, content, and prerequisites of the book, paper or other resource. Explain the nature of the resource so that readers can decide which one is best suited for them rather than relying on the opinions of others. Answers containing only a reference to a book or paper will be removed!

Answer (score 3):

Check out this, I guess this is the first paper where it was introduced. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321385902858