# Decay of spin-1 particle into two 1/2 particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

If particle of spin 0 decays in rest frame decays in 2 particles the angular distribution will be uniform. How it will change for particle with spin 1 decaying in pair of $e^{-} e^{+}$ for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will change a lot, in general, and will depend on the chirality properties of the interaction. Take a look at [this](https://indico.cern.ch/event/246009/attachments/422282/586290/CERN_23_4_2013_no_animations.pdf).

A quick example, of the type you should have had drilled into you in your introductory HEP physics course: consider the decay of J/ψ, spin 1, in its rest frame. Assume the spin of the ψ is pointing upwards. The photon EM interaction producing an $e^+e^-$ decay pair is vectorlike: it preserves chirality, so the two decay products flying off back-to-back *must* have opposite chiralities: either L & R, or else R & L. So, on their common axis, their total helicity, will be +1 or -1 , *never, never* 0.

(Their masses are so small, compared to the kinetic energy involved, that chirality and helicity are very-very close to each other, and treated as identical, for all practical purposes, here.)

This, then, means that the $e^+e^-$ decay pair loves to be  emitted along an axis in the ψ frame where its spin points up, the lepton or antilepton in the direction of this axis being R (helicity +1/2). The angular distribution of that lepton will be $|d^1_{1,1}|^2$, so $((1+\cos\theta)/2)^2$. So emission at
π/2 will be 1/4 of that; and at π, in the opposite direction, impossible!

More dramatically, if you chose the spin 0 state of ψ on that axis, the R fermion distribution on that axis will perforce be 0, since its distribution will be
$|d^1_{01}|^2=\sin^2 \theta /2$, its maximum probability occurring at right angles to this direction; and, of course, also vanishing back-to-back.

I hope you now appreciate the presence of the [Wigner *d* rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix#List_of_d-matrix_elements) on the most useful page of the PDG booklet, the one with [Clebsches, Spherical Harmonics, and d-functions](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2019-rev-clebsch-gordan-coefs.pdf)--pure gold.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I am also very curious on the derivation of this distributions. Maybe you can recommend me some books where I can study this topic?

Comment: Hmm... Try [Kutschke's Angular distribution cookbook](https://home.fnal.gov/~kutschke/Angdist/angdist.ps) , or illustrations of the Jacob Wick ancient classic article [here](http://epx.phys.tohoku.ac.jp/~yhitoshi/papers/angular.pdf). Admittedly, I haven't seen a good section in modern texts... I learned it from Feynman, of all people...

Comment: Some [resources](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252193/spinor-helicity-formalism-original-reference).

Comment: [This](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph218/Helicity_formalism.pdf) is a fine review.  The original [Jacob-Wick 1959 paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(59)90051-X)  has the full picture.  Frankly, every time an angular distribution is presented in a seminar, half the old-timers in the room are working out the helicity amplitudes in their head, with glazed eyes... It's true.

Comment: Thank you very much!